# Объединение двух запросов в 1

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть две таблицы. Пытался связать их с помощью джоинов, но может быть так, что по полю **PERSONID** результаты будут отличаться количественно. Соответственно, при использовании джоинов создаются лишние строки и результаты считаются совершенно неверно.
Данные из таблицы 1 (**cab_covid_vacc**):

```
ID   PERSONID GETWELLDATE QRCODESTART QRCODEEND

14        193 27.01.22                          
15        193 27.01.22                          
16        192 27.01.22                          
17        192 27.01.22                          
18       5687 27.01.22                          
19       5687 27.01.22                          
21       5242 27.01.22                          
22       5242 27.01.22                          
23       5243 27.01.22                          
24       5243 27.01.22                          
25       4726 27.01.22
```

Данные из таблицы 2 (**cab_covid_medotv**):

```
    ID   PERSONID  AVAILABLE STARTDATE ENDDATE

    27        193          1                    
    30        192          1                    
    31       5687          1                    
    32       5242          1                    
    33       5243          1                    
    39       4726          1                    
    40       4726          1                    
    36        193          1                    
    37        234          1
```

Сама суть в том, что мне нужно считать количество строк. Запрос первый:

```
select  b.city, count(case when cvacc.thenextvac = 0 then 1 end ) as firstvacc, count(case when cvacc.thenextvac = 1 then 1 end ) as secondvacc      
from PS_Persons d      
join Ps_positions a on d.lastposid = a.positionid      
join RB_Departments b on a.Department_Code = b.Code     
join RB_Positions c on a.Position_Code = c.Code   
left join cab_covid_vacc cvacc on cvacc.personid = d.personid
left join RB_Positions c2 on a.Position_Code2 = c2.Code     
where 1 = 1 and nvl(a.LEAVING_DATE, to_date('01.01.3000','DD.MM.YYYY')) > sysdate  and b.branch IN (1, 224, 181) and a.CONTRACTTYPE IN (1,2) 
group by b.city
```

Второй запрос абсолютно такой же, только меняется таблица, по которой идет подсчет:

```
select b.city, count(case when cmed.available = 1 then 1 end ) as medotv       
from PS_Persons d      
join Ps_positions a on d.lastposid = a.positionid      
join RB_Departments b on a.Department_Code = b.Code     
join RB_Positions c on a.Position_Code = c.Code     
join cab_covid_medotv cmed on cmed.personid = d.personid
left join RB_Positions c2 on a.Position_Code2 = c2.Code     
where 1 = 1 and nvl(a.LEAVING_DATE, to_date('01.01.3000','DD.MM.YYYY')) > sysdate  and b.branch IN (1, 224, 181) and a.CONTRACTTYPE IN (1,2) group by b.city
```

Я понимаю, что можно как-то объединить строки с count по городам (b.city), однако не знаю как. Union и Union all выдают строки с нулем и по принципу лестницы выдает результаты. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, 1 столбец был - город (b.city), а затем столбцы с COUNT с двух запросов. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: Попробуйте `count(distinct case when cmed.available = 1 then cmed.personid end )` т.е. считаем уникальные personid по условию

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно помогло!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.city, t2.city) city 
       t1.firstvacc, 
       t1.secondvacc, 
       t2.medotv
FROM (запрос 1) AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (запрос 2) AS t2 ON t1.city = t2.city
```

А совпадающую часть запросов (всё, кроме JOIN различающихся таблиц и группировки) затолкать в CTE.